# Wilcard (*) Match for Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

Is it possible to create a wildcard match using the Zend Framework Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname for the actual domain?  I tried the simple example below but the system would not recognize the route.  When I hardwired the route (login.domain.com), it would work properly.

```
resources.router.routes.login.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.login.route = "login.*"
resources.router.routes.login.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.login.chains.index.route = ":action/*"
resources.router.routes.login.chains.index.defaults.controller = "login"
resources.router.routes.login.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname ('login.:domain.:net');
    $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] = 'login.example.com';
    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http ();
    $match = $route->match ($request);
    var_dump($match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this possible without the :domain.:net both being explicit, i.e. without stipulating just one period?

i.e. I currently have

new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('sub.example.com',array('controller' => 'x'));

..but what I'd really like to do is:

new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('sub.:remainder',array('controller' => 'x'));

..whereby this route will match *any* hostname that begins with 'sub.' including sub.example.com, sub.another.example.com, sub.somethingelse.com, sub.com etc.

Doesn't seem to work though!

Anyone got this working?